# How to enable/disable javascript on a browser tab from server?

Tags: java, javascript, http

I ran into the following issue today:

I am trying to load a page through a proxy server.
When I try to access the URL directly the javascript is enabled and the page loads correctly. I see that javascript is enabled on the brower that I am using.
But when I try to access the URL through proxy, part of the page loads correctly only the js files don't get loaded and I see the following warning on top of the page.
            'This page works best with javascript enabled.'

I think, when I try to load the page through proxy, javascript is disable on that tab. Is there a flag that I can set in the response to enable javascript on the tab?

Comment: The server can't control whether the browser has JS turned on or not. My guess is that your proxy does not pass JS through.

Comment: Further to @Butt4cak3s answer - if you use http://www.anonymouse.org/ there is no Script support.

Comment: Thanks @Butt4cak3 but would that explain the 'This page works best with javascript enabled.' warning in the page? In the same browser, when I open the direct URL in a different tab, it works fine.

Comment: @Usha It's a message that is in the page by default and JavaScript removes it the moment it gets loaded. If JavaScript does not get loaded, no matter why, the message stays. If your proxy does not pass the scripts to your browser, it doesn't remove the message.

Comment: That's normal: web proxies typically block JavaScript because otherwise it does things that escape the proxy or just don't work anyway. If you use a different web proxy you may find one with the option to allow scripts, but that doesn't mean that they'll work correctly. If you need to proxy complex scripted pages you should use a real (SOCKS or HTTP) proxy.